# Python: add value and write output

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I need to get information from a list and `add a column year` from name. I still not sure how to add one field `'year'` in record. **Can I use append?**
And about output file, I just need use `outputcsv.writerow(records)` isn't it?
This is a part of code that I stuck:

```
filenames = ('babyQld2010.csv',     
    'babyQld2011.csv',
    'babyQld2012.csv', 
    'babyQld2012.csv',
    'babyQld2014.csv')

outFile = open('babyQldAll.csv','w') 
csvFile_out = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=',')

for filename in filenames:
    name, ext = filename.split('.')
    year = name[-4:]     #extract year from  file names
    records = extract_names(filename)

    # Get (name, count, gender)  from  list "records", 
    # and add value of "year" and write into output file (using "for" loop )
```

Output file look like:

```
2010,Lola,69,Girl
```

And input, I have 5 file `babyQld2010.csv, babyQld2011.csv, babyQld2012.csv, babyQld2012.csv, babyQld2014.csv` which contains:

```
Mia,425,William,493
```

and I have to sort it in format and I already done it and save in list `'records'`

```
Lola,69,Girl
```

now I need to add one field `'year' on 'record'` list and export `csv file`.

This is my full code:

```
import csv

def extract_names(filename):
    ''' Extract babyname, count, gender from a csv file,
    and return the data in a list.
    '''

    inFile = open(filename, 'rU')
    csvFile = csv.reader(inFile, delimiter=',')

    # Initialization
    records = []
    rowNum = 0

    for row in  csvFile:

        if rowNum != 0:

            # +++++ You code here ++++
            # Read each row of csv file and save information  in list 'records'
            # as (name, count, gender) 
            records.append([row[0], row[1], "Female"])
            records.append([row[2], row[3], "Male"])
            print('Process each row...')      

        rowNum += 1

    inFile.close()
    return(records)



#### Start main program  #####

filenames = ('babyQld2010.csv',     
    'babyQld2011.csv',
    'babyQld2012.csv', 
    'babyQld2012.csv',
    'babyQld2014.csv')

with open('babyQldAll.csv','w') as outFile:

    csvFile_out = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=',')

    for filename in filenames:
        name, ext = filename.split('.')
        year = name.split('.')[0][-4:]     #extract year from  file names
        records = extract_names(filename)
        for record in records:
            csvFile_out.write([year] + record)
    print("Write in csv file...")     

outFile.close()
```

Comment: Can you please show the example input/output for your program?

Comment: python provides `csv` ability: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the year from the csv file you can simply split the string at `'.'` and then take the last four characters from the first part of the split. Example -

```
>>> s = 'babyQld2010.csv'
>>> s.split('.')[0][-4:]
'2010'
```

Then just simply iterate over your list of records, which you say is correct, for each list within in, use list contatenation to create a new list with year at the start and write that to csv file.

I would also suggest that you use `with` statement for opening the file to write to (and even in the function where you are reading from the other csv files). Example -

```
filenames = ('babyQld2010.csv',     
    'babyQld2011.csv',
    'babyQld2012.csv', 
    'babyQld2012.csv',
    'babyQld2014.csv')

with open('babyQldAll.csv','w') as outFile:

    csvFile_out = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=',')

    for filename in filenames:
        name, ext = filename.split('.')
        year = name.split('.')[0][-4:]     #extract year from  file names
        records = extract_names(filename)
        for record in records:
            csvFile_out.writerow([year] + record)
```

Comment: line 62
    with open('babyQldAll.csv','w') as outFile:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

it shows like that

Comment: maybe you missed closing some paranthesis above that line? can you show complete code? In the quesiton.

Comment: sorry about that, i just back from work. I just updated it @AnandSKumar

Comment: I cannot reproduce an invalid syntax error, are you sure that is the line and the complete stack trace? If so, can you please update the question with the complete traceback?

Comment: I run and it appear: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\SIT111\A1\data\writeCSVTPL.py", line 71, in <module>
    csvFile_out.write([year] + record)
AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: Oh sorry, it should be `writerow()` , fixed it.

Comment: Yashh!!! It works! Thanks!!!
Anyway, one more question, i want to put csv source file and output file in 2 seperate folder 'data' and 'output', so how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: You can use absolute path, currently you are using relative path, give the absolute path to where you want to create the file, and it will get created at that place.

Comment: So I need to change this line?     inFile = open(filename, 'rU')

Comment: no you need to change the `filename` directly, in the tuple you create. And the filename you use in - `with open('babyQldAll.csv','w')` .

Comment: i still have no idea about that... i tried /data/baby2010.csv... and /output/babyQldAll.csv but it's not working

Comment: Try without the first '/'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just append the `year` column to each row as you read it in from your source files.  You can read in & write out each row as a dictionary so that you can use your existing column headers to address the data if you need to massage it on the way through.

Using the `csv.DictWriter()` method you specify your headers (`fieldnames`) when you set it up. You can then write them out with the `writeheader()` method.

```
import csv
file_list = ['babyQld2010.csv',     
             'babyQld2011.csv',
             'babyQld2012.csv', 
             'babyQld2012.csv',
             'babyQld2014.csv']
outFile = open('babyQldAll.csv', 'wb')
csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(outFile, 
                            fieldnames=['name','count','gender','year'])
csv_write_out.writeheader()

for a_file in file_list:
    name,ext = a_file.split('.')
    year = name[-4:]
    with open(a_file, 'rb') as inFile:
        csv_read_in = csv.DictReader(inFile)
        for row in csv_read_in:
            row['year'] = year
            csv_writer.writerow(row)

outfile.close()
```

Hope this helps.